# JQuery .get data count

Tags: jquery

I have a file (aa.html) contains the following:

```
 <p> Item1 </p>
 <p> Item2 </p>
 <p> Item3 </p>
```

I was able to read it using this:

```
$.get('aa.html', function(data) {
alert(data);
});
```

how can I know the number of Items inside (or count number of `<p>`)?

Comment: what about `alert(data.length);`

Comment: Hi, if u want to count the `<p>` tags, just use `$("p").length;`...hope it will help u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.get('aa.html', function(data) {
  var dom = $('<div/>').append(data);
  alert("# of <p> elements: " + dom.find('p').length);
});
```